# Is it possible to create a custom html attr as a tag

Tags: jquery, html, mailmerge

Is it possible to add a custom attribute in this format to a html element.

```
<div class="example" editor:edit></div>
```

( A bit like Mailchimp's merge tags)

If so, how would I go about targeting the element, preferably with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MDN's HTML attribute reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) implies that you should never create non-standard attributes.

This is the very purpose of the `data-*` attribute, which description in the list is: `Lets you attach custom attributes to an HTML element.`

Answer (score 3):

You can use data attributes.

```
<div class="example" data-editor="edit"></div> 

$(function(){
    console.log($('.example').data('editor'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm aware of data attributes, I just wondered if it possible could use that exact format.